# How to understand "quantifiable" and "disproportionate" in the context

Tags: vocabulary

> For most of us adults, the adolescent years occupy a *privileged* place
>   in our memories, which to some degree is even **quantifiable**: Give a
>   grown adult a series of random prompts and cues, and odds are he or
>   she will recall a ***disproportionate*** number of memories from
>   adolescence.

I encountered this sentence when I was doing sentence equivalence practices. The original question had *a privileged* and *a disproportionate* missing:

> For most of us adults, the adolescent years occupy ______ place
>   in our memories, which to some degree is even **quantifiable**: Give a
>   grown adult a series of random prompts and cues, and odds are he or
>   she will recall ______ number of memories from
>   adolescence.
>
> > A. a peripheral | B. a privileged | C. an arbitrary
> >
> > D. a disproportionate | E. a modest | F. an uncertain

I thought if memory can be **quantified** instead of being continuous and hard to count, the size must be relatively small, so I picked up A and E as my answer but it's wrong.

Comment: The **proportion** of adolescent memories can be easily quantified, and the final sentence explains how to do it. B and D make the point that they are looking for, but there is nothing in the text that gives this away. A and E would also work: at a pinch, C and F might make sense too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a misunderstanding of a poorly worded test question.

Comment: I have to disagree. This is a decent test question.

Comment: gre question lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colon punctuation after **quantifiable** indicates that what follows will explain or justify the use of that term.

So you're looking for a word that has to do with quantification, and **disproportionate** is the only one that truly involves quantification.  **modest** is a qualitative term, and **uncertain** refers to the unknown which cannot really be measured, though statisticians try to measure the *confidence* of a calculation. **Disproportionate** actually involves the idea of *ratio*.

The memories from adolescence turn out to be disproportionately greater in number than memories from both childhood and earlier adulthood when "grown adults"  are given "a series of random prompts and cues".

What sort of word goes into the first blank?

The adolescent years occupy a ___________ place in our memories, which to some degree is even quantifiable.

NOTE: You write in your question: "I thought if memory can be quantified..." However, it is not **memories** which are quantifiable but *the idea expressed by the missing word* which is quantifiable.  The verb **is** is singular; thus the antecedent of **which** cannot be the plural noun **memories**.

An *arbitrary* place whose arbitrariness is, furthermore, quantifiable?  No.

Arbitrariness is not a quantifiable or measurable characteristic. It is absolute.

A *peripheral* place, whose peripheralness, that is, whose unimportance, is,
 furthermore, quantifiable?

Unimportance is not a quantifiable or measurable characteristic. The idea of "not central" or "on the sidelines" is also an absolute.

A *privileged* place, that is a high-ranking place, whose rank is quantifiable? Yes. Rank is quantifiable or measurable to some degree. The high rank (privileged place) of adolescent memories vis-a-vis all other memories can be quantified by subjecting grown adults to random prompts and cues and then noting which stage of life memories triggered thereby belong to, and then expressing the results as a proportion.